# Copy to clipboard, textarea

Tags: html, css

I am a complete beginner in HTML and CSS, and new to this community, this is my first post, I have checked a lot of similar posts, but unfortunately wasn't able to find exactly what I am looking for. I really hope someone can help me as I have not been able to find a solution on my own.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

1. I have a text which I would like to copy with a button click.
2. The text should be copied in with line breaks and not in one line.
3. The text shouldn't be highlighted when it gets copied.

I have managed to do it on my own, but I think it's not the most convenient way, but as a complete beginner I wasn't able to find a better solution, if someone with experience can take a look and suggest other options I would really appreciate it.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<div class="columnen">
  <p>1. Line one.<br>
      2. Line two.<br>
      3. Line three.<br>
  </p>      
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea id="myInput" name="myInput">1. Line one.
2. Line two.
3. Line three.
  </textarea>
 </div>
```

The solution works, but the problem I have is that I have to edit each text two times, as I use the first part of the code visible for users and second part of the code invisible for users, but which actually makes the job done.

Maybe I can just style the class "textniz" or textarea, but I don't know how to stop it from highlighting the text.

Hopefully I have made sense with my request and someone from the website can take a look. Cheers.

Comment: Am sorry, I didn't completely catch where you are stuck at

Comment: Thank you for prompt replies. Sorry, I might have stated the question incorrectly. I will try again. If I'm trying to copy the text which will include line breaks and without highlighting it on the website, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: The code above was the solution I have found with one text (class="columnen") being visible for users and the second one (name="myInput") doing the job of copying the text, but I would like to know if its possible to combine those two together or somehow style the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### So, your goal is not to get the text area highlighted and not to fold the lines.

To stop the textarea from being highlighted, we can create an another textarea and put it away from the page and put the original textarea's value in our new textarea and select its value which will not be visible to the user, and the text will be copied. After copying, we can remove the newly created textarea.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var value = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var copyText = document.createElement("textarea");
  copyText.value = value;
  copyText.style.position = "fixed";
  copyText.style.top = "-1000vh";
  document.body.append(copyText)
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  console.log(value)
  copyText.remove()
}
```

```css
1. Line one.
2. Line two.
3. Line three.
```

```html
<div class="columnen">
  <p>1. Line one.<br>
      2. Line two.<br>
      3. Line three.<br>
  </p>      
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea id="myInput" name="myInput">1. Line one.
2. Line two.
3. Line three.
  </textarea>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for a reply. Can you advise if there is a way to style the box under the Copy text button with CSS? Sorry if those are newbie questions, but I really don't know the answer.

Comment: The solution you have sent to me is similar to the one I'm using currently, but is there a way to summarize two visible and invisible parts in one? So that what's displayed on the website is copied with line breaks and without a text being highlighted?

Comment: Hmm, we have create an other textarea with the same value of which is visible in the page, and the created one's text is selected and copied. Thats all, but to hide the text area, i just pushed that off the screen, that is I have set its `top` value to be `-1000vh` and its `position` `fixed` so that the new textarea does not create scrollbars on body. And after copying, the new textarea is removed

Comment: Is it possible to style the textarea box or it's standard and cannot be styled?

Comment: That can be styled with the tag name `textarea`, you can inspect it with your developer tools, find the approproate selector, of if you can, assign it its ID and style it.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I have tried and it works!